# Export different resolution of raster from QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, dem, raster-conversion

I'm currently sitting on a project where I have a DEM of an area that has been scanned. it currently has around 3-ish pixel per meter on export but I need to export it as 1 pixel per meter and also retain the coordinates of it. How would I go about doing this? As I understand I need to use the Warp tool maybe? But I've had no luck.

I've found a few tutorials but haven't been successful with them either. I'm a creative that's not usually working with GIS so I don't understand most of the terms so it's a bit hard to follow along to tutorials.

Here's an image of the problem, the x pixel count on the DEM is 9926 when its 3953m across, I need it to be 3953 pixels across in X
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Raster - projections - transform/reproject ... set a different resolution of the output file.

Comment: If you do not need to change the projection you can use simply Layer (right click) - Export - Save as... set resolution.

Comment: @Erik i do not have that option, only assign projection, extract projection and warp under that tab

Comment: @user30184 how do i know what resolution i should set it to so i get the desired result?

Comment: For 1 pixel per meter I would use value `1`. The unit of resolution is actually meters per pixel (or feet or degrees or whatever is the length unit of the coordinate system of the data). So in your metric case for 2 pixels per meter the value would be `1/2=0.5`.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please taker the [Tour]. Stating that you've tried but "had no luck" isn't the most direct way to get help here.  Instead, detail *exactly* what you tried (with screen shots, if necessary) and what the result was (error messages should be included as text).

Comment: @user30184 weird, i did it and the file went from 53gb to 138, can't open it in anything haha, something must have gone wrong

Comment: I suppose something similar than in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329483/file-size-inflation-using-gdal. If source file is compressed and output is not compressed it certainly affects the file size.